# Two Django projects, one Postgresql database, and Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a django project with two apps. One is a basic homepage all static with an app specific django admin to control various aspects of the site. The other is a eCommerce django app.

This is in one docker container. I have this connected to another docker container running the postgres image. Now, I have decided to split these two apps into two separate django projects and docker containers. Would it be reasonable to use just the one postgres container for both django containers? Or do I need to make two postgres for the two django containers?

Comment: 2 containers will be a good idea coz then you can easily work uninterruptedly.Suppose you wanna release a new image of one of them , then you need to bring one container down not both of them.i am heavily using docker compose these days and i believe loose coupling makes life easy rather than everything cluttered in one yaml file.one postgresql image is fine though.

Comment: @Ankur Interesting. So two postgres containers from one image for the two django containers. Makes sense. Yeah, I am just learning the advantages of loose coupling the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the right answer to this is "it depends".

If you're limited in resources and your apps are not really performance critical I think it's fine to have a single postgresql container (with couple of databases or schemas in there).

If you need to scale your apps separately or want to make them independent of each other, than go with two postgresql containers.

Finally, you can start with a single postgresql container (two dbs or schemas), and split it later if/when needed.